# Allocate Shards and replica to specific node

Tags: elasticsearch, replication, elastic-stack, sharding, elk

I am beginner to Elastic search ,
I have an elastic search cluster with 3 nodes in ec2 AWS, from these nodes 2 are spot instances, and one is on-demand instances. Since shards and replicas are distributed among all nodes.  I need to set that on-demand instance as a primary node means there should be allocated a replica of every index in the 3 nodes into the primary node(on-demand instance). So if even the spot instances get terminated I will not lose the data. Is there an way to configure it.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want to allocate primary shard to the on-demand instance?

Primary/replica shard level filtering is not possible currently. However, if your concern is regarding data loss, you don't have to worry so much because if the primary shards goes down one of the replica shard gets promoted to primary shard.

Comment: I mean the replicas of every shard should be allocated to the on-demand instance . So even the spot instances get deleted  i will not lose the data.  @DhireshJain

Comment: Regardless of where you have replicas stored, if an instance goes down causing a primary shard to get lost, one of the replica shard will get promoted to primary shards, so you won't lose data